# Visual studio 'Go to definition' does not bring full definition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

(Using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview version 16.2.0 Preview 3 and .Net Core 3.0)

I am confused about how the VS 'Go to definition' feature work.

If I place my cursor over `ImmutableList<T>` and press F12, it opens a tab named `ImmutableList [from metadata]` which shows:

```
public sealed class ImmutableList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, ICollection, IList, IImmutableList<T> {
```

However If I go to https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableList_1.cs#L19

I see:

```
public sealed partial class ImmutableList<T> : IImmutableList<T>, IList<T>, IList, IOrderedCollection<T>, IImmutableListQueries<T>, IStrongEnumerable<T, ImmutableList<T>.Enumerator>
```

I see some interfaces have been missing from what was shown with F12 (ie `IOrderedCollection<T>`)

Why is that F12 doesn't show the complete definition ? how can I get the correct one from within VS ?

Comment: Is `IOrderedCollection` public?

Comment: it is internal, is that why F12 hides it ?

Comment: Think of the problem this way - what would be the value of including internal interfaces (that you can't easily access or invoke methods against)? How might that explain why it doesn't show them?

Answer (score 0):

Looking here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition?view=vs-2019

It says:

> Note 
>   When you try to run the Go To Definition or Peek Definition
>   command for types or members that are marked as internal, Visual
>   Studio does not display their metadata as source code, regardless of
>   whether the referencing assembly is a friend or not.